# Unable to stream logs to the console of my deployed app in PCF using the cf logs command

Tags: logging, cloud-foundry

Iam not able to fetch logs by using "cf logs "  as the Pivotal Cloud foundry (PCF) documentation indicates. 
i have the cf version : 6.20.0.

I have used logback configuration in application and marked the logs to STDOUT. 
I am able to see the logs in the cloud foundry portal where application is deployed. However it is not streamed out to the console when i do the cf logs command.
How should i link my app to the loggregator component in PCF ?

Trying the "cf logs  --recent"
gives below output..

:~ Connected, dumping recent logs for app  in org  / space  as ...

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this issue. It was a white listing problem on our Cloud intrastructure. 
We solved it by whitelisting the target IP and port.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint for others with this problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.